# Showing two vectors are LD using cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, cross-product

> Suppose that $u,v,w,t$ are vectors in space such that $u\times v = w \times t$ and $u \times w = u \times t$. Show that $u-t$ and $v-w$ form a pair of linearly dependent vectors.

I'm supposed to calculate $(u-t) \times (v-w)$ and use that $x \times y = 0$ iff $(x,y)$ are LD, but I'm stuck.

$$\begin{aligned}(u-t) \times (v-w) &= u \times v - u \times w - t \times v + t \times w
\\ &= -t \times w - u \times t - t \times v + t \times w 
\\ &= t \times u - t \times v 
\\ &= t \times (u - v)\end{aligned}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement, as currently written, is not true. Take

$$\begin{align*}
u &= (1, 0, 0) \\
w &= (1, 1, 0) \\
t &= (0, 1, 0) \\
v &= (-1, 1, 0).
\end{align*}$$

It follows that

$$u\times w = u\times t = u\times v = w\times t = (0, 0, 1),$$

but

$$\begin{align*}
u - t &= (1, -1, 0) \\
v - w &= (-2, 0, 0),
\end{align*}$$

which are not linearly dependent.

However, if we change the second equality in the statement to be $u \times w = v \times t$, then your calculations will be slightly modified and show that it is true.